# How to write to ko.observable on an event?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using knock  out for my binding purposed and i am working on a share module. basically, there are couple of links and they all are basically calling the same function just with different values. For example, when you click on the Facebook then all the service with value "Facebook" and when and when you click on Twitter then call the function with the value "Twitter". But basically calling the same function. Now that there is not way to specify parameters from HTMl because all I can do is something like data-bind="click: Share". Here we cans see that I can not specify any parameters here.

Now I can create an ko.observable in my js file which this function will take as an argument... but I need a way to write on that observable from html  click event when different  links are clicked. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. Please edit your question for clarity (or maybe add some code) if my answer doesn't cover your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout passes the current context to any function used in data binding. This means that if you call `click: share` it will pass in the service you have bound. [Here is a fiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/zP7L2/1/), but I'll put in the code here since its pretty basic.

For more complex bindings, your object will likely have a `name` property, which you can use in place of `$data`, as well as use in your `share()` function.

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: services">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.share" />
</ul>​
```

Javascript:

```
data = [
"Facebook",
"Twitter",
"Flickr",
"SomeOtherWeb2.0 Service"
];

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    this.services = ko.observableArray(data);
    this.share = function(service){
        alert("You Clicked on: " + service);
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));​
```

Comment: I Exactly see your point. So basically I have to give a context to all my links and in your example data[] becomes that context. So guess my solution lies in using a data array. I am using all different links and those have no relation with each other while in your case you are producing it using templates and making sure that they all some from the same source and  you can relate them. thanks.

Comment: @Californicated, the data array was an example, to be used in place of the data source for your app. And in the the `click` context, the item in the array is the context, not the entire `data` array. There are ways to accomplish this functionality without tying the links together, but I would shy away from them. Knockout tries to keep you into the MVVM pattern, and using it will make your life easier down the road.